# How badly does switching kernel slow down or completely stop Mathematica running jobs?

Tags: parallelization, kernel

I have a question on how to run two or more Mathematica jobs on one laptop. For example, I use a local kernel to run a job. Then I open another job and choose Kernel configuration option and choose alternative local kernel to run another job. Then I found the first job is stopped. The number labels in front of the current bracket disappears. This makes me very upset. Because the computation is very expensive, it costs me three days. But then I switch the kernel to the original local, the number label comes back, but I am wondering this operation actually has killed the computation, which cannot continue as before, though the title still shows running, but it is a lie. I keep waiting for two hours without any output results. Does anyone have experience on it?

Comment: I do not understand what you were doing, or what you mean by "job". Are you using notebooks or the command line interface? What do you mean by "and choose alternative local kernel to run another job" and by "But then I switch the kernel"?  You tagged this as parallelization: are you using the parallel tools at all?

Comment: I did something as this http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12425

Comment: I see. Don't change the kernel of the notebook in which something is running. Open a new notebook, and set the new kernel in this second notebook.

Comment: Yes, I did so, but it is strange that this operation does not work. The second notebook still runs after the first one is finished.